# My adding program outputs SUPER WEIRD

Tags: string, vector, addition

I have been trying to read two numbers as string, convert them into int vectors, then add them for my lab at school (I loop this process 4 times). I have run my code to find very strange results.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void input(string &largeString1, string &largeString2);
void convert(string largeString1, string largeString2, vector<int> &largeInt1, vector<int> &largeInt2);
int asciiToInt(char ch);
void add(vector<int> largeInt1, vector<int> largeInt2, vector<int> &finalInt);
void output(const vector<int> finalInt);

int main()
{
    string largeString1;
    string largeString2;
    vector<int> largeInt1(12, 0);
    vector<int> largeInt2(12, 0);
    vector<int> finalInt(13, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        input(largeString1, largeString2);
        convert(largeString1, largeString2, largeInt1, largeInt2);
        add(largeInt1, largeInt2, finalInt);
        output(finalInt);
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
void input(string &largeString1, string &largeString2)
{
    cout << "Input:" << endl << endl;
    cin >> largeString1;
    cin >> largeString2;
}
void convert(string largeString1, string largeString2, vector<int> &largeInt1, vector<int> &largeInt2)
{
    int size1 = size(largeString1);
    int size2 = size(largeString2);
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
    {
        largeInt1[11 - i] = asciiToInt(largeString1[size1 - 1 - i]);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
    {
        largeInt2[11 - j] = asciiToInt(largeString2[size2 - 1 - j]);
    }
}
int asciiToInt(char ch)
{
    return (ch - '0');
}
void add(vector<int> largeInt1, vector<int> largeInt2, vector<int> &finalInt)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        if (largeInt1[11 - i] + largeInt2[11 - i] >= 10)
        {
            finalInt[12 - i] = finalInt[12 - i] + largeInt1[11 - i] + largeInt2[11 - i] - 10;
            finalInt[12 - i - 1] = 1;
        }
        else
            finalInt[12 - i] = finalInt[12 - i] + largeInt1[11 - i] + largeInt2[11 - i];
    }
}
void output(const vector<int> finalInt)
{
    cout << endl << "Output:" << endl << endl << "The sum is: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        cout << finalInt[i];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

My outputs first output seems to give the correct answers, but the next 3 outputs do not add up (pun not intended). Also, how do I get rid of the annoying leading zeroes?

Comment: Can you please post your inputs and outputs into the question?

Comment: I don't think you read my entire question. I am trying to add two integers and so inputs can be anything.

Comment: Yes of course your inputs can be anything, but if you post an example input that you tested,and the wrong outputs that you get, it will help up to diagnose the problem.

Comment: inputs: 1 1   1 1   1 1   1 1 outputs: 0000000000002 0000000000004 0000000000006 0000000000008